# What does “Integrating out field” mean?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, field-theory

In Schwartz’s QFT book, there is a couple of exercise problems of particle polarization in chapter 3. I have trouble with finding interaction terms from the given Lagrangians. Is it just okay to express the Lagrangians in momentum space?

[image]

Comment: sorry for adding pictures three time :(

Comment: Your title refers to the phrase "integrating over field" but that phrase doesn't appear anywhere in any of the questions. Are you asking what "integrating out" a field means? Because that is defined in the question.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 0):

By substituting $A_{\mu}$ for it's solution in terms of its Equation of motion, you are essentially removing $A_{\mu}$ as a dynamical degree of freedom, you only see it's imprint as it's effect on the current $J_{\mu}$.